# Django message history

Tags: django

I wonder if you have any ideas on this

I present messages as below - it works great, when there is an error it shows the error.

But, how do I retain these messages - so the user can see all of the errors they had since their session started?

I.e. if I working for a while, I might want to review all my form validation failures at the end.

Thanks

```
messages.error(request, ('ERROR: Your milestone was not created. Milestone points must be numeric. Please try again.'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Django's Sessions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views

```
def message_error(request, msg):
    errors = request.session.get('errors', []):
    errors.append(msg)
    request.session['errors'] = errors
    messages.error(request, msg)

def get_message_error_list(request):
    return request.session.get('errors', [])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).